# Function ReflectionParameter::export() is deprecated 7.4, alternative?

Tags: php, reflection, deprecated

I recently changed to Php 7.4 from 7.2 and I came across a deprecated function:

```
Function ReflectionParameter::export() is deprecated
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.export.php

what to use instead?

Comment: You could try casting the value to a string, not sure if the output is any different.

Comment: Why would it be different? Export() has its own parameters, ReflectionParameter instance didnt even get the "method" name, how could __toString() know what method I want to export?